# how to add documents to a collection after the collection has been cleared?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named "tweets". Before I save new documents, I would like to clear the collection first.

How do I achieve this? My code doesn't work as intended.

Edit: There might be some overlapping document ID

```
    // Delete existing tweets:
    db.collection('projects').doc(proj_id).collection('tweets').get().then(querySnapShot => {
        querySnapShot.docs.forEach(snapshot => {
          snapshot.ref.delete()
        })
    })

    // Add new tweets
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(tweets_need_to_save)) {
        db.collection("projects").doc(proj_id).collection("tweets").doc(key).set({
            id: key,
            text: value
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `.then()` chain to add new documents after deleting all the documents in the collection. See code below:

```
db.collection('projects').doc(proj_id).collection('tweets').get().then(querySnapShot => {
    querySnapShot.docs.forEach(snapshot => {
      snapshot.ref.delete()
    })
})
.then(() => {
    // Add new tweets
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(tweets_need_to_save)) {
        db.collection("projects").doc(proj_id).collection("tweets").doc(key).set({
            id: key,
            text: value
        })
    }
})
```